# Output links in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a piece of wordpress code that outputs a string (which is a url)

I need to convert this output to a link.

```
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Link", true);
```

The code is already inside  tags as there are other php calls in the file too.

How do I modify the code to output a link?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because PHP can echo literal HTML code, you can simply output the link inside a hyperlink.

```
echo "<a href=\"" . get_post_meta($post->ID, "Link", true) . "\">Your Link Name</a>";
```

Alternatively, you can choose to close and reopen the PHP tag before and after the echo statement. The above is the same as...

```
?>
<a href="
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Link", true); ?>
">Your Link Name</a>
<?php
```

The second method is handy when you have large blocks of output and you don't want to make individual echo statements all over the place.

Comment: That works great. Thanks. I tried something similar but had the wrong syntax. I don't really know PHP.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, "Link", true).'">'.get_post_meta($post->ID, "Link", true).'</a>';
```

or

```
$link=get_post_meta($post->ID, "Link", true);
    echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a>';
```